# R GGplot - object train not found

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm learning how to use R, but can't seem to get my bar chart to display. Feels like im making a very rookie error.

Here is the code:

```
> library(ggplot2)
> ggplot(train, aes(Q2)) + geom_bar(fill = "red")+theme_bw()+
+     scale_x_continuous("Age Brackets", breaks = seq("Under 18","Prefer not to say")) + 
+     scale_y_continuous("Count", breaks = seq(0,200,5)) +
+     coord_flip()+ labs(title = "Q2 - Age Brackets") + theme_gray()
```

Here is the error:

```
Error in ggplot(train, aes(Q2)) : object 'train' not found
```

SPSS file:

[image]

Q2 in RStudio

[image]

Data and function in RStudio Environment:

[image]

Comment: have you read in the file into R?

Comment: Try `read.spss` function in the `foreign` package or `spss.get` function in the `Hmisc` package.

Comment: @Daniel I've added additional screenshots. I believe the file is read into R.

Comment: @Matadeleo In your screenshot is no object named "train" . Also note that your data (named "data") is of class data.set, not data.frame : )

Comment: I am following the same tutorial & ended up here. This is what you need to do. Read the csv & then set the data frame to a variable named train. `train <- data.frame(read.csv('your.csv'))`. Then run the ggplot function & it should work

Answer (score 2):

The function is expecting the data you want to plot is named `train`. You should have a `data.frame` in your environment named `train`. Do you?

Comment: In environment I have a `data.set`, if I change out `train` for `data.set` I get the error: `Error in if (is.waive(data) || empty(data)) return(cbind(data, PANEL = integer(0))) : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

Comment: @Matadeleo What do `is.waive(data)` or `empty(data)` return?

Comment: @RuiBarradas Both return `Could not find function"

Comment: Your screenshot indicates `data.set` is a function. Your `ggplot` data, what you're substituting in for `train` should be in the `Data` section and its type should be `data.frame`.

Comment: @Matadeleo So they must come from an external package, not a `base R` package. You should start the script with `library(pkgname)`.